# Multiplying the denominator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$$\frac{2}{3} \gt -4y - \frac{25}{3}$$

My question is to solve this problem we need to multiply both sides by $3$. The result will be

$$2 \gt -12y - 25.$$

Why doesn't the numerator of both $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{25}{3}$ get multiplied?

Comment: The numerator does get multiplied. However the $3$ on the denominator cancels out the $3$ multiplied to the denominator leaving just the original numerator.

Comment: So is this simply a rule? there is no explanation it just "IS". If so, what does this rule apply to. Also, if the denominator for "25/3" got changed to "6". Would you still multiply both sides by 3? and achieve the same result based on your rule.

Comment: Because it's arithmetic. (2/3)x3=2. In other words $2/3>V\iff 3(2/3)>3(V)\iff 2>3(V).$ That is what multiplying an inequality or an equation by 3 actually means.

Answer (score 1):

As an expansion of what I said in the comments:

When we multiply the equation $\frac{2}{3} > -4y - \frac{25}{3}$  by $3$ we get the following equation

$\frac{2\times3}{3} > (-4y)\times3 - \frac{25\times3}{3}$. Simplifying the following we get

$\frac{6}{3} > -12y - \frac{75}{3}$.

Now $\frac{6}{3} =2$ and $\frac{75}{3} = 25$. Thus utilizing these known facts we can simplify the above equation giving us

$2 > -12y - 25$. So the numerators got multiplied by $3$, but then we divided by $3$, which amounts to returning to the original numerator. This is because multiplication and division are inverse operators.

From your comment, if you changed the $3$ in the denominator to a $6$ you would not get the same result. Instead of ending up with $25$, you would get $\frac{25}{2}$.

Comment: Why would it be 25/2 this time if both sides were multiplied by 3?

Comment: So you have $\frac{25}{6}$ and you are multiplying by $3$. You get $\frac{25*3}{6}$ which simplifies to $\frac{75}{6}$. Noticing that both $75$ and $6$ are divisible by $3$ allows us to reduce the fraction to $\frac{25}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{2}{3}
&>
-4y-\frac{25}{3} \\
3\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)
&>
3\left(-4y-\frac{25}{3}\right) \\
3·\frac{2}{3}
&>3·\left(-4y\right)-3·\frac{25}{3} \\
\require{cancel} \cancel{3}·\frac{2}{\require{cancel} \cancel{3}} 
&>
3·\left(-4y\right) -\require{cancel} \cancel{3} ·\frac{25}{\require{cancel} \cancel{3}} \\
2
&>
-12y -25 \\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like $\frac{a}{b}>c-\frac{d}{b}$ and you are trying to get rid of the fraction on the left side, then we have
$$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\left(b\right)>c(b)-\left(\frac{d}{b}\right)\left(b\right)$$
$$\frac{ab}{b}>c(b)-\frac{db}{b}$$
$$a\cdot\frac{b}{b}>c(b)-d\cdot\frac{b}{b}$$
$$a\cdot1>c(b)-d\cdot1$$
$$a>c(b)-d$$
So as you can see, the numerators are in fact multiplied by the denominator you are trying to remove, $b$, but it gets "cancelled out" because $b$ divided by itself is $1$ given that $b\ne 0$